# PreferenceFragmentCompat vs PreferenceFragment for API14+

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, material-design

My app targets API 14+. If I want material design in my PreferenceFragment, do I need to use PreferenceFragmentCompat or it is still possible with PreferenceFragment?

Comment: If the answer below satisfied your question you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine using `PreferenceFragment`. It is supported API 11+ so you should be fine.